# Methods for implementing contour plotting

Tags: math, graphics, vector-graphics

I need to implement a contour plotting algorithm (as opposed to just using one). The input is a (continuous) function f: R^2 - > R (the function is defined over the entire domain, not just for certain inputs). The output should be in vector form, i.e. a set of splines or line segments.

I'm looking for recommendations on how to implement this, preferably in the form of (scientific) papers.

I found some references to algorithms developed in the 80s ("Level Tracing Algorithm"). Have there been any development in this area in the past 30 years? What's the standard method(s) used to solve this problem?

The algorithm will be used for real-time visualization, so it needs to be fast while still producing decent results.

(Small, self-contained and well tested C/C++ implementations would be welcomed as well.)

Answer (score 6):

I recall the TI-89 calculator used a very simple scheme like this:

- Make a grid, experiment with mesh size
- Compute your function at each vertex of the grid
- For each square, if there are two values of f with different signs, there is something interesting inside. Assume it is the case in the following:

  - For each "interesting" side of the square (f has different signs at endpoints), find the zero of f on the side by bisection (or by linear interpolation if you're on low budget). There may be two or four interesting sides.
  - If there are two interesting sides, draw a straight line between the zero points.
  - If there are four interesting sides, draw a cross.

Now, you may want to refine the interesting squares adaptatively. The TI-89 had a damn small screen (160x120) and this was not necessary. The exact same method can be used inside an interesting square.

Answer (score 2):

See for instance [xfarbe](http://www.fhi-berlin.mpg.de/gnz/pub/xfarbe_doc.html).

Comment: There's no mention of how xfarbe computes its contour lines, so this is useless to me, unfortunately. And no, I'm not going to look at the source.

Comment: The README says "The numerical kernel is based on:
           Preusser, Albrecht
           Algorithm 671 - FARB-E-2D: Fill Area with Bicubics
           on Rectangles - A Contour Plot Program.
           ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software, Vol. 15,
           No. 1, March 1989, p. 79-89." See http://www.fhi-berlin.mpg.de/grz/pub/xfarbe/xfarbe-2.6c/README.html

Comment: Thanks. The paper doesn't seem to be freely available, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest the most straightforward method: consider you have to find a contour of `f(x,y) = Z` for certain `Z`. Then seed your field of plot, `D = subset(RxR)` with net of equilateral triangle mesh of vertices and edges, `M = (V,E,r)`, where `M` - mesh, `V` -set of vertices, `E` - set of edges, `r` - triangle side length, the `level of detail`, LOD. Then, for every vertex in `V`, compute the value of `f`. Then, for every edge in `E`, check if the edge (`e[k]`) has a value of `f` on it's vertices (`v[i]` and `v[j]` for example) on the different sides about `Z`, that is, if `f(v[i])>Z` and `f(v[j])<Z`. If so, than the contour line of `f(x,y) = Z` intersects this edge `e[k]` at a certain point (`c[k]`), which can be linearly approximated:

> t = ( f(v[i]) - Z ) / ( f(v[i]) - f(v[j]))
>   c'[k] = v[i]*(1-t) + v[j]*t

As the triangle with one edge contour intersection has second intersection at some of the remaining two edges (proof is trivial), we obtain a second `c'[k]`. Thus, for every triangle from `M` we have either none or single line segment, approximating the contour line. Drawing all the found segments will provide us an approximate contour plot of `f(x,y)=Z` with certain level of detail `r`. Lowering `r` will produce finer contouring, raising `r` will give the performance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make a data arrays f[i,j] for yours function at some grid, collect line segment from each cell and connect them later into a curve(s). You should keep in mind possible circles (i.e. presence of several closed curves in the grid). Exactly this algorithm is used in [MathGL](http://mathgl.sf.net/) (cross-platform GPL plotting library) -- see realization of mglGraph::Cont() function.